# error: invalid operands to binary >> (have 'float' and 'int')

Tags: c, floating-point, bitwise-operators, eeprom, pic24

I am trying to cast float to bitwise int in C. Here's my code snippet:

```
write_eeprom(INDEX_CONFIG_TEMPERATURE_OFFSET_HIGH_INT, (unsigned int) (temperature_offset>>16));
write_eeprom(INDEX_CONFIG_TEMPERATURE_OFFSET_LOW_INT, (unsigned int) (temperature_offset));
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary >> (have 'float' and 'int'),
```

while trying to compile. Here, temperature_offset is a float type and I am trying to cast it as high int and low int as I am trying to save data in EEPROM in 16-bit chunks (as I am using a 16-bit microcontroller). I know that the '>>' does not apply to float types. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Create a separate `unsigned int` variable and `memcpy` the float into it, then work on that.

```
unsigned int temperature_offset_int;
memcpy(&temperature_offset_int, &temperature_offset, sizeof(temperature_offset));
write_eeprom(INDEX_CONFIG_TEMPERATURE_OFFSET_HIGH_INT, temperature_offset_int >> 16);
write_eeprom(INDEX_CONFIG_TEMPERATURE_OFFSET_LOW_INT, temperature_offset_int & 0xffff);
```

Comment: you probably need to make sure that `int` has the same size as `float`. Otherwise this looks better than my feeble answer :)